# How to send custom data via parse push notification between iOS and Android devices?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am sending a Parse Push from an iOS device using the code below.

// iOS

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"john.doe@acme.com", @"email",
                          @"John Doe", @"name",
                          nil];
    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
    PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
    [pushQuery whereKey:@"device_id" equalTo:@"1234567890"];
    [push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
    [push setData:data];
    [push setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"John Doe wants to connect with you."]];
    [push sendPushInBackground];
```

On the Android side, I do receive the push notification, but can not read the data. The below code is what I'm using to read the data.

```
String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
```

The 2 string values for name and email are not in the jsonData string. Can someone give an example of how to send and read custom data between iOS and Android devices? I need to cover the other case as well when sending custom data (email and name) from Android and reading that data from an iOS device using Parse push notifications. Thanks!

Comment: [How to receive parse push notifiactions on an android device using parse.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454269/how-to-receive-parse-push-notifiactions-on-an-android-device-using-parse-com)

Comment: I've already tried what this link recommended, but still don't see the jsonData come back when I send from an iOS device. Please advise.